# facebook like box does not work

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I have a facebook fanpage: www.facebook.com/derwettprofi

I wanted to create a [like box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/). Although I use the code generated by facebook it does not work. I created the following simple html page:

```
<HTML>
    <BODY>
        <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fderwettprofi&amp;width=292&amp;height=62&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;header=false&amp;stream=false&amp;show_border=false&amp;appId=567203116676137" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:62px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

But when called in the browser it looks like this:
[image]

I do not understand what is happening? The response is empty. Why does it not work?

Comment: I am not %100 sure if it's the problem in your case but have you tried running your page from your web server instead of your desktop?

Comment: No I did not run it from my webserver. But that was the reason why it did not work. Thanks for the advice! You can also write an elaborate answer and I will then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the http:// in front of www. This happened to me as well

Answer (score 0):

it is because your website is on localhost. Try uploading it to an online host, that should solve your problem.